# How to derive Euler-Maclaurin sum formula from Taylor Series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, summation, gaussian-integral, euler-mascheroni-constant

[image: Here]

**Page 152 at** https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F978-0-387-73468-2.pdf

Hi readers, I have tried substituting y'(0) , y''(0) , y'''(0) and y''''(0) into equation A that is the first equation. However, still couldn't really get what Maclaurin derived for y(1). Anyone can provide some workings on how Maclaurin did that?

Comment: Any help would be useful for me!!

Comment: There seem to be some typos. Do you mean $y(1)=A-\frac 1 2B+\frac 1{12}C-\frac 1 {720}E+\frac 1{30240}G+\cdots,$ where $E,G$ are defined analogously?

Comment: Yes @Pythagoras , do you know how to derive it ? It would be helpful to me:))

Comment: I really want to know how Maclaurin derived it tho haha

Comment: The textbook has typo

Comment: Can everyone have access to the textbook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming convergence (so the formula works at least for polynomial $y$), the formula can be seen by linear algebra. One has part of the infinite dimensional matrix as follows: $$\left[\begin{array}{cccccccc}*&y(0)&y'(0)&y''(0)&y'''(0)&y^{(4)}(0)&y^{(5)}(0)&y^{(6)}(0)\\
A&1&\frac 1 2&\frac 1 6&\frac 1 {24}&\frac 1{120}&\frac 1{720}&\frac 1{5040}\\
B&0&1&\frac 1 2&\frac 1{6}&\frac 1{24}&\frac 1{120}&\frac 1{720}\\
C&0&0&1&\frac 1 2&\frac 1 6&\frac  1{24}&\frac 1{120}\\
D&0&0&0&1&\frac 1 2&\frac 1 6&\frac 1 {24}\\
E&0&0&0&0&1&\frac 1 2&\frac 1 6\\
F&0&0&0&0&0&1&\frac 1 2\\
G&0&0&0&0&0&0&1\end{array}\right]$$

By row operations to eliminate the higher-order components in $A$, one has $$y(0)=A-\frac 1 2B+\frac 1{12}C-\frac 1{720}E+\frac 1{30240}G,$$ modulo terms of order greater than  $6$. This shows that $$y(1)=y(0)+(y(1)-y(0))=y(0)+B=A+\frac 1 2B+\frac 1{12}C-\frac 1 {720}E+\frac 1{30240}G+\cdots.$$ (So my comment has a small typo as well.)

Comment: Hi @Pythagoras may i know how do you got the matrix above? Is it by guess?

Comment: They are just the coefficients in $A,B,\cdots$. Note that in $B$, they have a typo as well: It should read $B=y(1)-y(0)=y'(0)+\frac 1 2y''(0)+\cdots.$ The formulas for $A,B,C,\cdots$ follow from the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Comment: i got it now lol

Comment: Thank you for your help !! So kind

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sxTiXSXNuM6cWQ-_C31EZR2oKrgOeO_8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi Sir, Shouldn't B which is y(1)-y(0) be y(1)+y(0) as stated in Wikipedia. I shared the link above to check it out.

Comment: I am confused on that part only, cuz it must match the exact formula stated in Wiki :))

Comment: A is the integral

Comment: I am confused on that part only, cuz it must match the exact formula stated in Wiki :))

Comment: @MaximusSu, It depends on the way you write the formula, but definitely the formula is related to Bernoulli numbers:  https://oeis.org/search?q=2%2C12%2C-720%2C30240&sort=&language=english&go=Search  (I was too lazy to check it earlier, but when you time, you can try to derive the general terms using Bernoulli numbers.) I will double check everything within a day, depending on availability.

Comment: "I am confused on that part only, cuz it must match the exact formula stated in Wiki :))": Note that the formula in Wiki is NOT an identity (equality), it is just an asymptotic approximation, so it is irrelevant to drop or change a few terms.

Comment: so you mean +f(a) which has the denominator of 2 in Wiki can actually be changed to -f(a) as it will not affect the results much?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127083/discussion-between-pythagoras-and-maximus-su).