# How to correct the derivation of Euler Maclaurin Formula from Taylor Series?

Tags: integration, matrices, discrete-mathematics, derivatives, summation

[image]

[image]

[image]

Hi readers, after discussing with Pythagoras at [How to derive Euler-Maclaurin sum formula from Taylor Series?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4187486/how-to-derive-euler-maclaurin-sum-formula-from-taylor-series/4187788?noredirect=1#comment8683591_4187788), the **euler-maclaurin sum formula** derived seems to be a **bit flawed**. The **- sign i pointed out in the picture should be a positive because the real formula in Wiki Euler-Maclaurin is + sign!**
Can anyone spot any mistake?
[image]

Comment: Barring the convergence issue, I did not see the "flaw" in Maclaurin's formula which is exact (your previous question). Now you brought in the Euler-Maclaurin formula, which arises in a different context (as approximation), so one needs to be careful when making comparison. I will try to give a first step to link the two formulations in the answer (to this question), leaving the proof as exercise to you.

Comment: @Pythagoras Isn't the one in my working as in your working too the proof for E-M summation ?

Comment: I suspect the proofs are closely related, but one needs to add Euler's intelligence! (Please consult the Wiki to find a proof of E-M.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a first look, it may seem to be "flawed", but remember $y(1)$ is not a sum in itself. (Since the left hand side already differs, how do you expect the right hand side to be the same?)

To bridge the seemingly inconsistency, try to look at this way: If in the left hand side of Euler-Maclaurin formula, you take the sum of two terms, then you get
$$f(a)+f(b)\sim \int_a^b f(x)~dx+\frac{f(a)+f(b)}2+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{B_{2k}}{(2k)!}(f^{2k-1}(b)-f^{2k-1}(a)),$$ which means that you would have $$\frac{f(a)+f(b)}2\sim \int_a^b f(x)~dx+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{B_{2k}}{(2k)!}(f^{2k-1}(b)-f^{2k-1}(a)).\qquad (1)$$ The good news is that when $a=0,b=1,$ and $f=y$, formula (1) becomes an identity in the Maclaurin's formula! To see this, [recall](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4187486/how-to-derive-euler-maclaurin-sum-formula-from-taylor-series/4187788?noredirect=1#comment8683565_4187788) we have $A=\int_0^1y(z)~dz,$ $$y(0)=A-\frac 1 2B+\frac 1{12}C+\cdots\qquad (2)$$ and $$y(1)=A+\frac 1 2B+\frac 1 {12}C+\cdots .\qquad (3)$$ Adding (2) and (3) and dividing by two, one has $$\frac{y(0)+y(1)}2=A+\frac 1 {12}C-\frac 1{720}E+\frac 1{30240}G+\cdots,$$ which is an exact formula.

Now the exercise for you is to prove (in the context of Maclaurin) that
$$y(0)+y(1)=\int_0^1 y(z)~dz+\frac{y(0)+y(1)}2+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{B_{2k}}{(2k)!}(y^{(2k-1)}(1)-y^{(2k-1)}(0)),$$ which is equivalent to (2) or (3), but with the closed form expressions in the summands.

Comment: Now, I fully understand how Maclaurin derived it. Thank you sir, I believe this is the easiest analytic method for the derivation so far i can understand. LoL.

Comment: Thank you @Pythagoras